# PyQt5 File Dialog - the last opened file becomes the initial path for the next use of the tool

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to build a GUI with PyQt5. The relevant part of the code is shown below. So i created a QTextEdit and a button. The Path to the file is shown on the QTextEdit and the button opens a file dialog to choose another file and updates the QTextEdit widget. It works good like this. The Filename is used at a couple of different places all over the tool.

I give it a initial path at the moment. But that is not what i want to do. I rather want my tool to have the last opened file as an initial path. So in the beginning the QTextEdit widget should be empty as long as i open a file. That should be saved when i close it and be the initial path when i use my tool again the next time. Does anyone have an idea how i can do that?

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.Filename = "C:/Users/Marvin/Desktop/Kostenkontrolle Programm/Database.csv"
        self.path.setText(self.Filename)
        self.Open_Database.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog)


    def open_dialog(self):
        self.Filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        self.path.setText(self.Filename[0])
```

Comment: Consider using QLineEdit instead of QTextEdit, as according to your explanation only one path will be displayed in it. On my system, QFileDialog.getOpenFileName actually opens right at the last used path. Isn't that enough for your purpose?

Comment: I am actually using QLineEdit. Sorry, mixed that up. 
No, for me that doesn't work. It always opens the path of the .py file. I basically want to display the chosen path on the QLineEdit Widget. That works, but i don't want this line: self.Filename = "C:/Users/Marvin/Desktop/Kostenkontrolle Programm/Database.csv"
I don't like to give it a fixed file or path inside the code. And i also don't want to be forced to always choose a file whenever i use the tool. I want the tool to use the file that i already used the last time without giving a specific file in the code itself.

Comment: If you want the last used folder to be the default starting folder of the file dialog the next time you open the program, you probably need to store the path in a file on your hard drive...

Comment: Ah yeah, that would be a solution that might work. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Dialogs from [QFileDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#public-functions) accept "directory" as an input parameter.

So I would suggest replacing

```
self.Filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
```

by

```
self.Filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(directory=self.path.text())
```

This should give you the desired effect (or at least an idea on how to get there).

If you want to store the file path somewhere else than in the program code, you could use [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings

self.settings = QSettings("pyqt_settings.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)
# for saving a value to the ini
settings.setValue("LastFile", filename)
# for loading a value from the ini
self.settings.value("LastFile")
```

Comment: Hm, okay if i understand that right directory=self.path.text() basically opens the path that is written in the QLineEdit Widget correct? 
That is helpful, but not exactly what i am looking for. What i want to do is somehow get rid of this line: self.Filename = "C:/Users/Marvin/Desktop/Kostenkontrolle Programm/Database.csv" 
On default i want to tool to always use the same file, that i want to give on the GUI. But only the first time i use it. I don't want to open the same file whenever i am using the tool. So the initial file/path should be the last file that was opened.

Comment: I also don't want to write anything in the QLineEdit Widget on the GUI. The purpose of that widget is only to display the selected file. I hope you understand what i am trying to do here.

Comment: I see. I have added a proposal to save the "user settings" to an ini-file using qsettings.